# PHP mySQL constructing parent data from child class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have a database with 3 tables. `person`, `player`, and `coach`. The `person` table contains things that the `player` and `coach` have in common, such as `firstName`, `lastName`, and `email`.  The `player`, and `coach` tables then have a link back to the `person` table with a `personId` field.  Every person who accesses the site has a `person` entry.  Additionally, some users may also have `player` or `coach` entries.  The database is set up this way to maintain normalization.

In my code, I have a `person`, `player`, and `coach` class.  The `player` and `coach` inherit from `person`.  Below is a truncated version of the `person` and `player` classes.

```
class person{  
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName){
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }
}

class player extends person{
    private $position;
    private $jersey;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $position, $jersey){
        parent::__construct($firstName, $lastName);
        $this->position = $position;
        $this->jersey = $jersey;
    }
}
```

As a heads up I'm quite new to OOP so bear with me if there's things I don't know.

(side question, what are the above classes considered, Views?)

Now in order to populate these I use what I understand to be the Model classes (is that right?).

```
class personModel{
    public function getPerson($personId){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `personId` = '$personId'";
        //skipping some sql stuff in here
        return new person($sql['firstName'], $sql['lastName']);
    }
}
```

But now the heart of my question, is how do I implement a `playerModel`?

```
class playerModel{
    public function getPlayer($playerId){
        //would I do a join SQL here?
        //or would I call personModel::getPerson()
        //or do both these options couple the two classes too tightly?
    }
}
```

Would some kind of `factory` class be another option? If so, how would that be done?

I need to be able to construct `person`, `player`, and `coach` objects, because I have users that will fall into all those categories.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated, and I'll be checking back often if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will begin with your side question, since the terminology is the first important part when speaking about OOP:

- Your classes `person`, `player` and `coach` are the Model. The intention of the Model is to project the important part of reality into a program, so that you (as a programmer) can intuitively work with the terms regarding the business domain.
- A View is not a standard OOP term, sometimes it is an abstraction inside a DB, so that you work with a View about one or more tables instead of the tables directly. Sometimes it is a GUI for a model.

Your classes `personModel` and `playerModel` are less a model than a persistence controller or, as you said, a factory. If you would like to learn OOP and the possibilities to load/save a Model from/into a relational DB, you can easily write your own code, similar to your SQL code. A class `DBManagement` could do the trick with operations like `loadPersons()`. That operation queries the DB, builds all person objects and returns them. Similarly the saving can work with `updatePerson(person $person)`.

Later you can use some kind of ORM (Object Relational Mapper) persistence framework (I don't have experience with PHP myself, but [doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) could be interesing. In Java or .Net often [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is used).

Addionally I would suggest that you design your model in another way. Indeed you had the right idea to let `player` and `coach` inherit from `person`, so that you can share common attributes like the `firstName`. But in this case, that model is not flexible enough to allow what you mentioned in your last sentence, that some users fall in all categories. A special case is when a Person, which is actually a Player, will become a Coach. For example, if Martin is a player but shall become a coach now, you have to swap one Martin object for another. That means that Martin is not the same Person as before, just because he becomes a coach, and that sounds strange, doesn't it?

Instead you can define, that every user is **always** a `person`. Some users are `coach`es, some others are `player`s, some are both and some are none. But always a `person`.

Some pseudo code for illustration:

```
class Person {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    List<PersonRole> roles;
}

abstract class PersonRole {}

class Coach extends PersonRole {}

class Player extends PersonRole {
    int position;
    string jersey;
}
```

This way every user (=Person) can have none to every role. If a user has a role then in that role object you can save specific role attributes for that user. Of course, a person's role list can change over time, according to what role(s) the person actually has.

A neat sideeffect is that this model is more in line with your database schema, so that you should have no trouble to translate the relational DB schema into a model instance and vice versa.